# <Anylogic>How to specify the accrual rate for each type of product

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

How to specify the accrual rate for each type of product?

I want to specify the percentage of occurrence for each product number set in OptionList.
Currently, it is random.

I need help from you guys. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the task is to sample from a range of products (P01-P08) at different rates. For example, P01 to be sampled twice as likely as P02. If that is the case, then this can be achieved using a [Custom Distribution](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/stochastic/custom-distribution.html).

Of course, a more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve would help to refine the answer further.